# Merged Sort Algorithm

Tags: python

I have a merge algorithm which is really fast: it's currently set up to check unknown words between lists; this function checks common words, I need to change the function below to check if words are in vocab or wds or neither I don't properly understand the function so any comments about what specific lines do would be great.

def find_unknowns_merge_pattern(vocab, wds):

```
result = []
xi = 0
yi = 0

while True:
    if xi >= len(vocab):
        result.extend(wds[yi:])
        return result

    if yi >= len(wds):
        return result

    if vocab[xi] == wds[yi]:  # Good, word exists in vocab
        yi += 1

    elif vocab[xi] < wds[yi]: # Move past this vocab word,
        xi += 1

    else:                     # Got word that is not in vocab
        result.append(wds[yi])
        yi += 1
```

def check(bigger_vocab,book_words):

```
    both = [ ]
        for words in bigger_vocab:
            for people in book_words:
                if words == people:
                    words.split()
                    both.append(words)

    return both
```

The problem is it takes at least 5 seconds whereas my merge algorithm takes 0.08. How can I call that function so I can make this one faster?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is your "merge algorithm" in python? What is the purpose of `check()`? What have you tried to call your merge algorithm and why is it not working? Please give an example of calling `check()` with the desired and actual output. To ask better questions, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes its in python currently what it does is return words that are'nt in a specific list, it's not working because I don't know how to change it

Comment: Please unindent lines 4-8 to avoid extra confusion; also, you're talking about "my merge algorithm", so please share that code as well. Finally, since you're talking about some time-of-execution tests, show the input you have tried (the described behaviour should be reproducible for us to help).

Comment: I added the function at the top

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to find words that appear in bigger_vocab and book_words? If so:

```
both = list(set(bigger_vocab).intersection(book_words))
```

Comment: o I did that so my solution was right! and then I assume I do a similar thing to check if the words are'nt in either list right?

Comment: they said i have to modify the merge function itself not write a new function